# Dynamically change transaction fee using delegate service

Tags: transaction-fees

### My setup:

1. API service holding a bitcoind Full Node.
2. Client Wallet - I have no control over that system.
3. User application - Who gets the barcode for payments.

   - So, **My API (1)** only has the **Receiving Address** of the **Client wallet (2)**.

### The problem:

Let's say my client is a hotel, I want the **API (1)** to set the maximum fee for the transaction if the **user (3)** wants to get a room today and the minimum fee available if the user will set a reservation for two weeks from now.

### Leading question:

Is it possible without any control over **my clients (2)** wallet?